# Send a video from ROS to OpenCV app

Tags: ros, opencv, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to publish a .avi/mp4 file through ROS to my OpenCV app. How do I do so?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255347/send-a-video-from-ros-to-opencv-app./) by [Zig](https://answers.ros.org/users/29455/zig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is something [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) can do for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0